ASP.NET App Crashing on Somee Due to Unregistered Package Despite Uploading DLL Files
I have installed a package in my asp.net application. I have hosted the app using free tier of somee platform. The app is crashing since the package is not registered with somee. I have uploaded the bin folder which contains the dll files for the package but the app is crashing on importing class from the package.

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="CONNECTION_STRING" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>


The package class is not being imported


How are you creating the publish? The .dll's are NOT to be placed in the bin folder by you, but in fact correctly referenced in the application. Thus the act of building, or publishing the application will result in such .dll's being placed in the bin folder. You NEVER want to manually place .dll's in the bin folder, and in fact before a build, it often a good idea to delete all files in the bin folder. So, when you do a web publish, that build process will automatic determine which .dll's are to be placed in the bin folder - this is not a manual process. So, how are you publishing this site?

To publish the website on Somee, all the folders are uploaded manually, and then the application's starting point is referenced manually in default.asp. I have uploaded the project zip file and extracted it on Somee.

That's fine if you copy manually or even use ftp or even use a jump drive. However you are thus using a publish to a local folder.  In other words you are still using the projects publish option   and you always publish to a local folder and you always use the delete files before publish then right? And this is a web site application? In other words the source code pages are not placed on the server,  right?

In other words, you still using the project publish option, and publishing to a local folder, and that local folder is what is finally transferred to the production server by any means you choose. In other words, the publish option is still be used. During this publishing, then all source code files (the aspx.vb files) are stripped out, and NOT included in the publish then right? During the publish the .dll's for the site are compiled, and then copied to the bin folder, along with ANY referenced .dll's you have. So, the publishing process should take care of what .dll's are to be included.

I've tried everything, but the app crashes on a specific page where the class is being imported from the package library. What would you recommend to fix this issue?

Well, we first have to know how you publishing this site. As I stated, you should be going to build->publish site. You thus are to publish (say to a local folder).  This will ensure that all referenced .dll's are copied to the bin folder, but MORE important ensure that correct resoution of such dll's is done correctly. So, in the project references you have say iTextShap shown as a reference. When you publish to the local folder then those .dll's should be copied correctly to the bin folder. And then you are to copy that published folder to the server - not your source project.

Reference say to iTextSharp should NOT be in the bin folder. That will be taken care of at publish time. So, try using the publish option to a local folder, and then that's what you copy to the production web server. That's the recommend way to solve this issue (by using the publish option). You don't want to copy the aspx.vb files to the server, and if you look close at that new published folder, you see that the source code files (aspx.vb) are not included, and if you look at the bin folder, then the .dll's should correctly exist. I STRONG suggest when publishing, you check the delete files
